# Максимальная длинна целого числа в c++

Tags: c++

Задача - найти количество счастливых билетов длинны N. Решил, и всё бы хорошо, но... Счастливых билетов из 8 чисел = 4816030, из 12 = 39581170420, но вот как посчитать для 22? Для подсчёта суммы использую long long int, но даже сюда не влезает 294056694657804068000 (количество для 22значного билета). Использовать длинную арифметику или есть решение намного проще?

Comment: Можете считать в строку и искать суммы цифр.

Comment: Ну, надеюсь, вы не перебором ищете? :) Если достаточно чисел порядка 36 степени, то можно попробовать реализовать длинную арифметику из двух `long long int`'ов самостоятельно, но все зависит от того - это вам для дела (тогда берите, скажем, boost::multiprecision и не мучайтесь) или для преподавателя, который жаждет увидеть ваше умение...